# Extract Twitter handlers from string using regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I Would like to extract the Twitter handler names from a text string, using a regex. I believe I am almost there, except for the "`>`" that I am including in my output. How can I change my regex to be better, and drop the "`>`" from my output?

**Here is an example of a text string value:**

```
"<a href=\"https://twitter.com/PlaymakersZA\" target=\"_blank\">PlaymakersZA</a>, <a href=\"https://twitter.com/Absa\" target=\"_blank\">Absa</a>, <a href=\"https://twitter.com/DiepslootMTB\" target=\"_blank\">DiepslootMTB</a>"
```

**The desired output would be an array consisting of the following:**

```
PlaymakersZA, Absa, DiepslootMTB
```

**Here is an example of my regex:**

```
var array = str.match(/>[a-z-_]+/ig)
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'd say, use `document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="twitter.com"])` and iterate over each and get the `textContent` from DOM. If you want to use regex, use capturing group [`/>([a-z\-_]+)/ig`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/jwLqektt/) and extract first captured group value.

Comment: Or use `str.match(/>[a-z-_]+/ig).map(function (x) {return x.substr(1);})`

Comment: You can use a second `.match()` in worst case... Where you dont match `(?!>)`

Comment: @Wasted Can you perhaps give me more detail on implementing a second match? I am VERY new to regex. Thank you!

Comment: I just meant you could match the Elements of the Array again but now you got your solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use match groups in your regex to indicate the part you wish to extract.

I set up this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gbw0hz7g/1/) to demonstrate.

Basically, you surround the part of the regex that you want to extract in parenthesis: `/>([a-z-_]+)/ig`, save it as an object, and execute .exec() as long as there are still values. Using index 1 from the resulting array, you can find the first match group's result. Index 0 is the whole regex, and next indices would be subsequent match groups, if available.

```
var str = "<a href=\"https://twitter.com/PlaymakersZA\" target=\"_blank\">PlaymakersZA</a>, <a href=\"https://twitter.com/Absa\" target=\"_blank\">Absa</a>, <a href=\"https://twitter.com/DiepslootMTB\" target=\"_blank\">DiepslootMTB</a>";

var regex = />([a-z-_]+)/ig

var array = regex.exec(str);
while (array != null) {
  alert(array[1]);
  array = regex.exec(str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just strip all the HTML

```
var str = "<a href=\"https://twitter.com/PlaymakersZA\" target=\"_blank\">PlaymakersZA</a>, <a href=\"https://twitter.com/Absa\" target=\"_blank\">Absa</a>, <a href=\"https://twitter.com/DiepslootMTB\" target=\"_blank\">DiepslootMTB</a>";
$handlers = str.replace(/<[^>]*>|\s/g,'').split(",");
```